# java: combined instanceof and cast?

Tags: java, casting, instanceof, dynamic-cast

(Please no advise that I should abstract `X` more and add another method to it.)

In C++, when I have a variable `x` of type `X*` and I want to do something specific if it is also of type `Y*` (`Y` being a subclass of `X`), I am writing this:

```
if(Y* y = dynamic_cast<Y*>(x)) {
    // now do sth with y
}
```

The same thing seems not possible in Java (or is it?).

I have read this Java code instead:

```
if(x instanceof Y) {
    Y y = (Y) x;
    // ...
}
```

Sometimes, when you don't have a variable `x` but it is a more complex expression instead, just because of this issue, you need a dummy variable in Java:

```
X x = something();
if(x instanceof Y) {
    Y y = (Y) x;
    // ...
}
// x not needed here anymore
```

(Common thing is that `something()` is `iterator.next()`. And there you see that you also cannot really call that just twice. You really need the dummy variable.)

You don't really need `x` at all here -- you just have it because you cannot do the `instanceof` check at once with the cast. Compare that again to the quite common C++ code:

```
if(Y* y = dynamic_cast<Y*>( something() )) {
    // ...
}
```

Because of this, I have introduced a `castOrNull` function which makes it possible to avoid the dummy variable `x`. I can write this now:

```
Y y = castOrNull( something(), Y.class );
if(y != null) {
    // ...
}
```

Implementation of `castOrNull`:

```
public static <T> T castOrNull(Object obj, Class<T> clazz) {
    try {
        return clazz.cast(obj);
    } catch (ClassCastException exc) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Now, I was told that [using this `castOrNull` function in that way is an evil thing do to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3933609/java-unchecked-cast-from-x-to-y-how-to-implement-castornull/3933848#3933848). Why is that? (Or to put the question more general: Would you agree and also think this is evil? If yes, why so? Or do you think this is a valid (maybe rare) use case?)

---

As said, I don't want a discussion whether the usage of such downcast is a good idea at all. But let me clarify shortly why I sometimes use it:

1. Sometimes I get into the case where I have to choose between adding another new method for a very specific thing (which will only apply for one single subclass in one specific case) or using such `instanceof` check. Basically, I have the choice between adding a function `doSomethingVeryVerySpecificIfIAmY()` or doing the `instanceof` check. And in such cases, I feel that the latter is more clean.
2. Sometimes I have a collection of some interface / base class and for all entries of type `Y`, I want to do something and then remove them from the collection. (E.g. I had the case where I had a tree structure and I wanted to delete all childs which are empty leafs.)

Comment: I would use _instanceOf_ instead of _class.cast_ to avoid unnecessary exceptions in _castOrNull_, but apart from that you seem to have perfectly normal helper. Let **Tom** clarify what he meant.

Comment: If Y is a _superclass_ of X, you need no cast at all - did you mean _subclass_?

Comment: While this isn't a one-liner in Java, the performance of instanceof and casting is quite good.  I posting some timing in Java7 around different approaches to the problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16320014/java-optimization-nitpick-is-it-faster-to-cast-something-and-let-it-throw-excep/28858680#28858680

Comment: both of your examples seem to violate the "Is a" test for subclasses.  For instance, why wouldn't your nodes have a "deleteEmptyChildren" method?  My guess is because you are combining it with some other class where it should actually "has-a" pointer to the other class.  In general I think you are just over-using inheritance a little.  Remember to always prefer encapsulation over inheritance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Now, I was told that using this castOrNull function in that way is an evil thing do to. Why is that?

I can think of a couple of reasons:

- It is an obscure and tricky way of doing something very simple.  Obscure and tricky code is hard to read, hard to maintain, a potential source of errors (when someone doesn't understand it) and *therefore* evil.
- The obscure and tricky way that the `castOrNull` method works most likely cannot be optimized by the JIT compiler.  You'll end up with at least 3 extra method calls, plus lots of extra code to do the type check and cast reflectively.  Unnecessary use of reflection is evil.

(By contrast, the simple way (with `instanceof` followed by a class cast) uses specific bytecodes for instanceof and class casting.  The bytecode sequences can almost certainly will be optimized so that there is no more than one null check and no more that one test of the object's type in the native code.  This is a common pattern that should be easy for the JIT compiler to detect and optimize.)

Of course, "evil" is just another way of saying that you REALLY shouldn't do this.

Neither of your two added examples, make use of a `castOrNull` method either necessary or desirable.  IMO, the "simple way" is better from both the readability and performance perspectives.

Comment: Ah, thanks for that information! So you would also argument that I should not use `castOrNull`? Or how would you value those contra-points against my given pro-points? (Because after all, avoiding a dummy variable can also lead to more readable and shorter code.)

Comment: The only pro point that I can discern is that is avoids using a temporary variable in some cases.  For me, that is a purely cosmetic issue.  Use of a temporary doesn't make the code any less readable IMO, and shorter code is not a readability advantage either.  (And BTW it is not a "dummy" variable because it is used.)

Answer (score 20):

Starting Java 14 you should be able to do `instanceof` and cast at the same time. See https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/305.

Code example:

```java
if (obj instanceof String s) {
    // can use s here
} else {
    // can't use s here
}
```

The variable s in the above example is defined if `instanceof` evaluates to true. The scope of the variable depends on the context. See the link above for more examples.

Comment: Perfect. I knew I remembered something getting added for this in the past few years but I couldn't remember the syntax.

Comment: This is amazing and I wish I had learned about it as soon as it came out.

Answer (score 5):

In most well written/designed Java code the use of instanceof and casts never happens.  With the addition of generics many cases of casts (and thus instanceof) are not needed.  They do, on occasion still occur.

The castOrNull method is evil in that you are making Java code look "unnatural".  The biggest problem when changing from one language to another is adopting the conventions of the new language.  Temporary variables are just fine in Java.  In fact all your method is doing is really hiding the temporary variable.

If you are finding that you are writing a lot of casts you should examine your code and see why and look for ways to remove them.  For example, in the case that you mention adding a "getNumberOfChildren" method would allow you to check if a node is empty and thus able to prune it without casting (that is a guess, it might not work for you in this case).

Generally speaking casts are "evil" in Java because they are usually not needed.  Your method is more "evil" because it is not written in the way most people would expect Java to be written.

That being said, if you want to do it, go for it.  It isn't actually "evil" just not "right" way to do it in Java.

Answer (score 3):

IMHO your `castOrNull` is not evil, just pointless. You seem to be obsessed with getting rid of a temporary variable and one line of code, while to me the bigger question is *why you need so many downcasts in your code*? In OO this is almost always a symptom of suboptimal design. And I would prefer solving the root cause instead of treating the symptom.

Comment: Well, there're many libraries in Java which we don't design, but have to use. (Mentioned iterator being the one example)

Comment: @Nikita, fair enough, if you use a badly designed but at the same time indispensable Java library, you hardly have options. My personal guess is that such libraries should be very rare though. If a library is this awkward to use, then either noone uses it, or sooner or later someone starts to develop a better alternative.

Comment: I have extended my question a bit to show 2 cases where I sometimes use it. I don't really like hard rules to really **never ever** use something and I think my provided two cases are valid cases where you could do it like this. You might be more extreme about this than me but I guess you would also not be so extreme to never ever use code like this. And then, if you happen to have such a case, I always like to have the most clean solution and that was what I am asking here about. :)

Comment: @Albert, I don't like to say "never" either, especially here on SO ;-) I have been working with legacy code most of my career, so I had to learn to be pragmatic about living with suboptimal solutions. Using `instanceof` is a standard idiom, easy to understand to anyone, and - as Stephen C pointed out - easy to optimize. And I personally have no issues with temporary variables.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know exactly why the person said that it was evil.  However one possibility for their reasoning was the fact that you were catching an exception afterwards rather than checking before you casted.  This is a way to do that.

```
public static <T> T castOrNull(Object obj, Class<T> clazz) {
    if ( clazz.isAssignableFrom(obj.getClass()) ) {
        return clazz.cast(obj);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I doubt that he meant that because I asked for better code and the code which I have posted here was his own suggestion.

Comment: A similar alternative was discussed in the comments to the linked answer, and Tom did not prefer it over the above variant.

Comment: @Albert: missed that...since that's the case, I would say that most likely it is as Péter's answer says, a question of suboptimal design.  But really, in order to figure out exactly why he believes it wrong to do, you have to wait for his response (if he ever gets back to you).

Answer (score 0):

Java Exceptions are slow. If you're trying to optimize your performance by avoiding a double cast, you're shooting yourself in the foot by using exceptions in lieu of logic. Never rely on catching an exception for something you could reasonably check for and correct for (exactly what you're doing).

[How slow are Java exceptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299068/how-slow-are-java-exceptions)